# jQuery UI Tooltip delay with no effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone please explain how one might delay the tooltip without appending any effects? It seems to me the only way you can 'delay' anything is by messing with the 'show' attribute, but when you do so it must be bound with an effect, like so:

```
show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to delay the display of the tooltip before it's animated, or just not specify an effect?

Comment: I want the tooltip to appear after 5 seconds (say) only if the area is still being hovered. No effects. No fade-in, none of that stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in delay parameter along with the duration like:

```
show: {
  delay: 5000,
  duration: 0
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eL8q59a6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You may be happy to learn that you can achieve exactly this effect without any scripting at all (in either jQuery or in plain javascript).

A single CSS `transition` will produce the same effect:

```css
p {
line-height: 24px;
}

p span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 0 6px;
line-height: 22px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,127);
border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,0);
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0s linear 2s;
}

p:hover span {
opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover me <span>I am a tooltip</span></p>
```

Comment: Yes, fair comment. I hadn't initially reflected on the fact that if you quickly hovered and then moved the mouse away, the `setTImeout` would still be triggered. I guess the solution would be a `setInterval` which repeatedly incremented a counter - if the user moves the mouse away, the interval and the counter can both be reset. I've deleted the JS version - it's not good enough. I am happy with the pure CSS solution though, so I'll let it stand.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by setting the options on the tooltip object after the above didn't work for my specific app.

```
// Initialize tooltips.
$( '.tooltip-wait' ).tooltip();

// Add 5s delay before showing the tooltip.
// http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-option
$( '.tooltip-wait' ).tooltip( "option", "show.delay", 500 );
```